# How can I avoid TeamViewer‎ 9 from asking for an administrator password everytime I open it?

Tags: macos, administrator, teamviewer

On Mac OS X, I have recently upgraded from TeamViewer‎ version 8 to 9.

I uninstall old application properly and reinstalled it by double clicking dmg and following instructions.

Now every time I want to open teamviewer (by clicking the icon in `Applications` folder, it's asking me for a password.

[image]

Notes :

- Previous version (TeamViewer‎ 8) was running fine.
- I am running on a non administrator account.
- I have try to uninstall/reinstall TeamViewer‎ several times + reboot, but without success.
- When TeamViewer‎ open at startup (eg : after reboot) it start normally, without asking password.

Comment: Based on the dialog this is intended behavior.  Its likely the rights were changed.

Comment: It happen everytime i start teamviewer. i do not think its intented.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that extracting TeamViewer.app from the install-PKG works without errors if all you want to do is connecting to another TeamViewer.
Tested with the current version, v12.0.72647.

Mount the DMG, then in a temporary directory:

```
xar -xf /Volumes/TeamViewer/Install\ TeamViewer.pkg 
cat TeamViewerApp.pkg/Payload | gunzip -dc | cpio -i
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299907

Answer (score 1):

1) Install it in the first place with Admin privileges.

or

2) Right click on TeamViewer and click **Properties** then **Advanced**. Check **Run as administrator**. This should run it ad Administrator every time.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, my gf needed help but she doesnt have admin rights on her machine.

I found this one

> For the instant customer: TeamViewer QuickSupport
>
> Simple and small customer module, runs immediately without
>   installation and does not require administrative rights - optimized
>   for instant support

[Here](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/mac.aspx), under "Additional downloads"